# Zabbix - Trigger dependencies (multiple % CPU load)

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

i have 3 triggers on the one item.
BTW It reads precent utility from windows server from WMI by bash script.

Question is.
How to make dependence between 3 triggers. for example when CPU load is more then 90% doesnt make any sense to activate trigger with 70% or 50%.
I need see only last alert. How to make cascade? If 90% ...i dont need 70 and 50. If 70% i dont need see 50%..... (lot of alerts with no sense)

Triggers for one server:
{Server_windows_reading_from_WMIroc_percUtility.sh[{HOST.HOST},"_Total"].avg(5m)}>90
{Server_windows_reading_from_WMIroc_percUtility.sh[{HOST.HOST},"_Total"].avg(5m)}>70
{Server_windows_reading_from_WMIroc_percUtility.sh[{HOST.HOST},"_Total"].avg(5m)}>50

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure [trigger dependencies](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/4.4/manual/config/triggers/dependencies) on host or template level.

The `50`threshold trigger will depend on the `70`, which will depend on the `90` trigger.